# Unable to merge System.Data.SQLite.dll and System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll into single .exe file using ILMerge

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I developed Desktop Application using C#.net.I Merge all .dll and .exe into one .exe but except System.Data.SQLite.dll and System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll are not merged with that .exe.Is there any alternate solution for that problem.

Comment: check this http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=54e52d4c6f . Its an issue in sqlite

Comment: you could embed them as binary and load them into memory at runtime

Comment: You could store them in the resources of your exe-file, but then you are bound to use late binding. Easier would be to have bootstrap exe, which will extract exe files and all dlls into temp folder and then run exe (with optional clean up after the work). This is what self-extracting achieves can do.